# Bind event to IFrame body change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can fire an event if the contents of the body of an IFrame changes.

```
<iframe name="upload-iframe-1" id="upload-iframe-1" frameBorder="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>

</iframe>
```

Tried this but does not fire

```
 $("#upload-iframe-1").contents().find('body').on("change",function (e) {
        alert("changed");
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't care about IE10 or earlier, you have a better chance of doing what you want with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `$(window).unload()` This might help you to detect page unload from within iFrame.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
   return "Handler for .unload() called.";
});
```